# Dealing with Unicode range in Python

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I am trying to test if a given string is within the Katakana range or not.

I tried the solution asked here : [Python and Unicode Blocks for regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145232/python-and-unicode-blocks-for-regex). But still, my output is "None".                                               What am i  missing here ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
print re.search(u'[\u30A0-\u30FF]', u'カタカ')
```

Comment: Using python 2.7 on Windows

Comment: I notice in the linked question that they use `u'[\u30a0-\u30ff]'` while you use `u'[\u30A0-\u30FF]'`.  Could that be the difference?

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you actually saved the file in UTF-8?

Comment: @SethMMorton: the hex digits in unicode escapes aren't case-sensitive.

Comment: @Wooble I don't deal with unicode often (read: ever), so that was just a shot in the dark.  It's a good fact to know though, in case I ever need to deal with unicode.

Comment: @SethMMorton ,i tried with both. Getting same results.

Comment: @shamim As I shared in my previous comment I know nothing about dealing with unicode in python, so I will be of no help.

Comment: @Wobble , thanks for the quick reply. Could you please elaborate on the "saving the file in UTF-8" part and how to do it. Just jumped headfirst into a project and am still figuring stuff as i go along.

Comment: @shamim: what text editor are you using, and how are you saving the file? (To test, I directly copy-pasted the code in your question into PythonWin, saved, and ran, and got the expected Match object).

Comment: @Wooble, Aha !! got it. i was using PyScripter but then i too tried on PythonWin and got the match object. Thanks a ton !!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using Windows. You specify that the source file is UTF-8, but Windows doesn't use UTF-8 - it uses various code pages, depending on the language version and settings in Windows itself.

Many editors will have a way to override the Windows code page and save a file as UTF-8. Notepad for example has an `Encoding` list on the Save As dialog.